# Data Validation. Data is different from Remote browser vs Local Browser

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation

I am facing issue at work. In our QA Automation we use Jenkins to execute test cases, Jenkins will use remote browser, I am able to watch remote browser through VNC Viewer. We also use docker containers for parallel execution. (Which, by the way saves a lot of time.)
So I was doing Data Validation, of course I execute test cases on my local machine, push the code and fire Jenkins, to execute in local browser. And here is the problem. I noticed that some data in remote browser is different from local browser. In local browser test cases pass, but in remote they failed, because data is different.
Do I need to do some configuration? Did some one have similar issue?

Comment: CICD machines are usually slower, you should check logs and increase waits accordingly

Comment: Check time zone for Jenkins agents if data related to time

Comment: Thank you guys. I was also thinking about Time Zone. Gonna try that.